# how to delete folders but not files in a folder by cmd

Tags: cmd, dos, rm, rmdir

How to delete folders but not files in a folder by `cmd`?

Such as, there is a direcory:

```
c:\image\1.png
c:\image\2.png
c:\image\3.png
c:\image\*.png
c:\image\folder1\*.png
c:\image\folder2\*.png
....
```

Now I don't know how to delete all the folders (and subfiles) `folder1`, `folder2`...", only remain the files `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, `4.png` ...

Answer (score 4):

```
for /d %F in (c:\image\*) do rd /s /q "%F"
```

Double up the percents if used within a batch file